# Pandas get most common and last value in certain category, after groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with categorical variable and several attributes for each row:

```
df = ID  C1  C2  .... Cn   flag
      1  a   b         c   True
      1  a   c         d   False
      1  q   t         p   False
      1  g   y         p   False
      2  r   h         k   False
```

For each column, and for each value of ID, I want the most common (and num of the occurences) and the last value.
I am also want to know if it has at least one 'True' in the column flag.
So I will get:

```
out = ID c1_common c1_common_n c1_latest c2_common c2_common_n c2_latest ...  has_flag 
       1    a          2             g         y        1           y          True
       2    r          1             r         h        1           h          False
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> adding a new column (flag)

```
out = (df.filter(regex='[^flag]').melt('ID')
         .groupby(['ID', 'variable'])
         .agg(common=('value', lambda x: x.mode().head(1)),
              common_n=('value', lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1)),
              latest=('value', 'last')).unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
         .assign(flag=df.groupby('ID')['flag'].max().tolist()))

out.columns = ['_'.join(x) if x[1] else x[0] for x in out.columns.to_flat_index()]
print(out)

# Output
   ID C1_common  C1_common_n C1_latest C2_common  C2_common_n C2_latest Cn_common  Cn_common_n Cn_latest   flag
0   1         a            2         g         b            1         y         p            2         p   True
1   2         r            1         r         h            1         h         k            1         k  False
```

---

As your previous question, you have to flatten your dataframe before counting occurences. Finally, group by ID and Cx then aggregate some variables:

```
out = (df.melt('ID').value_counts()
         .rename('count').reset_index('value')
         .groupby(level=['ID', 'variable'])
         .agg(common=('value', 'first'),
              common_n=('count', 'first'),
              latest=('value', 'last'))
         .unstack('variable').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1))

out.columns = out.columns.to_flat_index().str.join('_')
```

Output:

```
>>> out

   C1_common  C1_common_n C1_latest C2_common  C2_common_n C2_latest Cn_common  Cn_common_n Cn_latest
ID                                                                                                   
1          a            2         q         b            1         y         p            2         d
2          r            1         r         h            1         h         k            1         k
```

Comment: Thanks! I get: KeyError: "Column(s) ['count'] do not exist"

Comment: I renamed the output of `value_counts`. Does it work now?

Comment: Now its working 10x

Comment: Please see new edit, adding a new column. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
col_list = df.columns[1:-1]

common = {'{}_common'.format(c):(c,lambda x: x.mode().iloc[-1]) for c in col_list}
common_n = {'{}_common_n'.format(c):(c,lambda x: x.eq(x.mode().iloc[-1]).sum()) for c in col_list}
latest = {'{}_latest'.format(c):(c,'last') for c in col_list}

agg_dict = {**common,**common_n,**latest}

df.groupby('ID').agg(**agg_dict,has_flag = ('flag','any')).sort_index(level=0,axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID C1_common  C1_common_n C1_latest C2_common  C2_common_n C2_latest
0   1         a            2         g         y            1         y
1   2         r            1         r         h            1         h
```

Comment: Please see new edit, adding a new column. Can you please help?

Comment: i made an update